# Else statement after multiple if statements

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quick theory question

```
if x:
    y

if a:
    b

if 1:
    2

else:
    3
```

Bottom "else" only affects last if?

Comment: Yes, of course. Did you try running an example yourself?

Comment: Note that ``else`` is not a separate statement. It is a part of its preceding statement (if allowed), in this case an ``if`` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the grammar:

```
if_stmt ::=  "if" assignment_expression ":" suite
             ("elif" assignment_expression ":" suite)*
             ["else" ":" suite]
```

A `suite` is, roughly speaking, a series of indented statements. So `x` is an assignment expression, and `y` is the suite associated with the first `if`. Because the next token is `if`, it starts a new `if` statement rather than continuing the first `if` statement in any way.

Thus, you have three separate `if` statements. The first two have no associated `elif` or `else` clauses; the third one has an `else` clause.